# Display the icon of my application in contact list

Tags: android

I just finished the development of my app in android. It has integration with contact list. Now i want to add my app icon in contact list of phone like Facebook, Google and Whatsapp icons. For the contacts that are registered to my app i wish to display my app icon on the contact list next to that particular contact name. Clicking on the app will redirect me to my app.

I have a faint idea that it maybe done by contact provider. I also know this maybe achieved by being able to add my application to the settings->accounts . But i do not know how to do it.

I have already gone through these similar questions but none of them provide adequate answers. 
[How to add custom app tag in native android contact app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181117/how-to-add-custom-app-tag-in-native-android-contact-app)

[Link Android application with contacts/phonebook programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816035/link-android-application-with-contacts-phonebook-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

> I have added custom mime type in android contacts list. After a long research i decided to share this with you guys, i have tested this on all Android cell phone including android 9.0[here is link](https://github.com/soogoodadnan/custom-mime-type)